# Dynamic value for NestJs controller

Tags: nestjs

I would like to specify the arguments for NestJs Controllers (and Post, Get, etc) dynamically (the particular use case is to make them configurable).

E.g.

`@Controller(config.get('whatever'))`

Is this possible? Can't find a mention in the docs, but it seems like a reasonable use case, e.g. when switching between environments.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack to do this, but you can create a factory provider, that all it does is set metadata for the `@Controller()`. It could look something like this:

```js
{
  provide: Symbol('CONTROLLER_HACK'),
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
    const controllerPrefix = config..get('whatever') ?? 'defaultValue';

    Reflect.defineMetadata(
      PATH_METADATA,
      controllerPrefix,
      ControllerToHaveTheAtControllerOverridden
    );
  },
  inject: [ConfigService],
},
```